# Saving Edits in Data Grid View VS 2012

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I'm trying to save the edits that I do in a Data Grid View in Visual Studio 2012. I can edit them fine, and they appear to save if I change context between tabs of my program. But when I close the program and open it back up, they aren't saved into the DB. How do I keep the changes that have been made when the program closes?

The program is connected to an Oracle 11g DB if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please tell us which datasource type you are using to fill the datagrid, if it is an ASP.Net datagrid or a DataGridView control in WinForms and also if you implemented persistency (for example, in the onClose event of the form, or a Save button, or anything to persist data changes)

Comment: It is a DataGridView control. The onClose event seems like it would be what I'm looking for, but I don't see that anywhere in the properties window of the grid view. Would I have to write that function myself? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ok, I understand it is a Windows Form application. I supose you have a DataSet (because you mentioned you use Oracle DB) Then you have to add code to persist changes to the database in the Close event. This article gives you a first look on how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I should be able to modify that code to work for me. What I'm not sure of, is where to put it though. I have 6 tabs on the top of my form that each contain a DataGridView that links to a different table in my database. Where in the code for them would I insert this?